# Is there any way to make Tkinter look less windows 95ish?

Tags: python, tkinter

I was wondering if there was a way to make tkinter more aesthetically pleasing.

Comment: Somewhat out of scope, but you might want to just look at wxPython, depending on how far you've gotten, and your deployment needs (packaging wxWidgets apps can be... fun).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [ttk](http://docs.python.org/library/ttk.html) module is in the upcoming Python 2.7 release.

Comment: It's also available in 3.1. It's very nice.

Comment: Will 2.7 be more similar to 2.6 (what I'm currently using)?

Comment: @anteater, yes, 2.7 is the last compatibility version of the 2.* series of releases -- definitely more similar to 2.6 than any 3.* is or will ever be.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [PyGtk](http://www.pygtk.org/) or [PyQt](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt), both have very nice python bindings from what i have heard. There's also the possibility of [Tile](http://tktable.sourceforge.net/tile/), which is getting integrated into tkinter in the (near?) future.

So, choose another GUI toolkit, or wait :).

Comment: The wait wasn't too long -- Python 2.7 final was release on July 3!-)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use an alpha version of Python to get ttk, you can download and use the [pyttk library](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyttk/0.3.2) from the package index (or use easy_install to get it of course).

Comment: Not a long wait for a final release of Python 2.7 -- it was released on July 3.